# SCSS psuedo:after and "class" with ampersand

Tags: css, sass

What I'm attempting to do is apply a `transition` to the element that has an `active` class applied. Basically I'm trying not to duplicate my SCSS (even though I know it will be duplicated in the CSS once compiled). All the `active` class will do is change the `bottom-border-color` of the triangle.

```
> li {

    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
        border-left: 30px solid transparent;
        border-right: 30px solid transparent;
        bottom: -100px;
        left: 50%;
        @include transform(0, -50%);
        @include transition(border-bottom-color .3s ease-in);

        &.active {  // this obviously doesn't work - nor does &.active:after
            border-bottom-color: $color-bg-green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaring `&.active::after` one scope above doesn't work?

Comment: Did you *look* at the compiled CSS?  You should try validating it.  The answer would be obvious.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos wow, brain fart - thx =\

Comment: @cimmanon - relax dude, I'm sure you miss simple stuff carelessly a lot like everyone else - we all need an extra set of eyes from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it needs to be written as below. I don't think you can chain the `.active` class inside of the `:after`.

```
> li {

    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
        border-left: 30px solid transparent;
        border-right: 30px solid transparent;
        bottom: -100px;
        left: 50%;
        @include transform(0, -50%);
        @include transition(border-bottom-color .3s ease-in);
    }    

    &.active:after {
        border-bottom-color: $color-bg-green;
    }

    /** alternative if you have properties to set for .active **/
    &.active {
      someProperty: someValue;

      &:after {
        border-bottom-color: $color-bg-green;
      }
    }
}
```